# Marionette: can you use the same event configuration for a trigger and an event?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

If I set up a Marionette view using the same event configuration for both a trigger and an event, only the trigger seems to get fired. Here's a simplified example: clicking `.button` should run `show` and trigger the `select:something` event. However, it only triggers the event.

```
var MyView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  ui: {
    'button': '.button'
  },

  triggers: {
    'click .button': 'select:something',
  },

  events: {
    'click .button': 'show'
  },

  show: function() {
    // won't fire
  }
});

var view = new MyView({});
view.on('select:something', handleSelect); // will fire
```

The [Marionette trigger docs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.3.1/marionette.view.html#viewtriggers) suggested that setting `stopPropogation` to `false` would help, but that didn't change the behavior for me:

```
triggers: {
  'click .button': {
    event: "select:something",
    preventDefault: true,
    stopPropagation: false
  }
}, ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marionette.View delegateEvents codes is:

```
// behavior events will be overriden by view events and or triggers
  _.extend(combinedEvents, behaviorEvents, events, triggers, behaviorTriggers);
  Backbone.View.prototype.delegateEvents.call(this, combinedEvents);
```

Events will be overriden by triggers because that events hash is before triggers hash in _.extend. 
You could use different key in events and triggers hash. The code like this:

```
var viewtemplate = _.template('<button class="button show-btn">show</button>');

var MyView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  template: viewtemplate,
  triggers: {
    'click .button': 'select:something',
  },
  events: {
    'click .show-btn': 'show'
  },
  show: function() {
    console.log('click .show-btn');
  }
});
```